# Process takes more time to complete in successive iterations

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have the following code and I'm noticing that the process takes more time to do its thing in each iteration. The line `myProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(stream);` takes around 200ms in the first iteration and in the 500th iteration it takes 3000ms. I'm assuming this line awaits untils there's something in the output buffer to read from, so it follows that myProcess takes increasingly more time to push data to the output stream in every iteration, why does this happen? How can I fix this?

```
while(i<1000){
   using (Process myProcess = new Process())
   {
      myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
      myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin";
      myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"-i fileName -map 0:a -f mp3 pipe:";
      myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

      myProcess.Start();                           

      myProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(stream);        
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to close the `StandardOutput` stream? Or `Flush` the `BaseStream`?

Comment: I've tried that but it hasn't worked